# Jekyll - Individual post with same layout as when all posts are together in a feed

Tags: jekyll

I want to be able to link to a single post on my jekyll blog and have it keep the default layout structure. The problem is if I use the default layout on the post layout, the page of all posts also uses that layout so the layout is rendered multiple times on the all posts page and creates issues. How can I link to a single post while using the default layout and still have my posts page with multiple posts in a feed use the same layout and not run into problems?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Can you please give us more details? Some example file structures and page mocks would be helpful. Better yet, post a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: I got it all figured out at Jekyll talk. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out, but in that case please post the answer or consider deleting the question if you no longer need an answer.

Comment: @KevinWorkman yup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out at Jekyll talk. See here:
 https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/remove-layout-under-certain-conditions/1660

Basically I needed to use includes for my post structure rather than placing the post directly.